# Adding a custom register page, changes the page title - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, register, page-title

I am adding a custom register pop-up to all pages by adding the following block in the `default.xml` file in my custom theme:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register_pop" template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml"></block>
```

But it cased all the pages to have the title: `Create new customer account`. The method works fine and the register form works well, but all the pages now have their titles replaced, is there any way around it without making too many changes? I am very green in Magento and am not very familiar with the tool. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Magento version: 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look into the `Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register` reveals that following code is responsible for your wrong title ;

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Create New Customer Account'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

So, you should override this block in your own module and inject class `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` and call `getFullActionName()` on the object and apply corresponding  condition to run it only when it is `customer/account/register`.

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Happy to help !

Comment: i overrided the register block file and changed title, that didn't change for me. cleared cache also

Comment: Recheck that you've successfully overridden the file, it should work.

Comment: I am also trying to override but not working could you plz help

Comment: Have you asked a question? let me know your code.